# How to use array of TreeNode of PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to create timeline with primefaces tree element. I have list of month names. I want put this list to every year like in picture below.[image]

I`m using jsf and ManagedBean names TreeBean.

My jsf:

```
enter code here  <h:form id="tmLine">  
         <div style="width:30%; float:left; ">

      <p:tree id="treeSingle" value="#{treeBean.root}" var="node"
                style="border:none; border-right:1px solid #aaa;width:100%; border-radius:0px;background:#fff; font-size:100%; " 
                        selectionMode="single"  
                        selection="#{treeBean.selectedNode}" animate="true" >  

                 <p:ajax event="select"  update=":tmLine:info"/>

                 <p:treeNode>  
                    <h:outputText value="#{node}" />  

                </p:treeNode>  
              </p:tree>

                </div>


                <div style="width:69%; float:left;  margin-left:1%;">
                 <h:outputText value="#{treeBean.testt}" id="info"/> 
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both"/>
                   </h:form>
```

TreeBean is:

```
enter code here  public class TreeBean{

private TreeNode root;
  private TreeNode selectedNode;  
 public TreeBean() {  
        root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);  
        TreeNode node0 = new DefaultTreeNode("2011", root);  
        TreeNode node1 = new DefaultTreeNode("2012", root);  
        TreeNode node2 = new DefaultTreeNode("2013", root);  


        TreeNode node00 = new DefaultTreeNode("Ýanwar", node0);  
        TreeNode node01 = new DefaultTreeNode("Fewral", node0);
        TreeNode node02 = new DefaultTreeNode("Mart", node0);  
        TreeNode node03 = new DefaultTreeNode("Aprel", node0); 
        TreeNode node04 = new DefaultTreeNode("Maý", node0);  
        TreeNode node05 = new DefaultTreeNode("Iýun", node0); 
        TreeNode node06 = new DefaultTreeNode("Iýul", node0);  
        TreeNode node07 = new DefaultTreeNode("Awgust", node0); 
        TreeNode node08 = new DefaultTreeNode("Sentýabr", node0);  
        TreeNode node09 = new DefaultTreeNode("Oktýabr", node0); 
        TreeNode node10 = new DefaultTreeNode("Noýabr", node0);  
        TreeNode node11 = new DefaultTreeNode("Dekabr", node0); 


        TreeNode node100 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.0.0", node10);  
    }  

    public TreeNode getRoot() {  
        return root;  
    }  

    public TreeNode getSelectedNode() {  
        return selectedNode;  
    }  

    public void setSelectedNode(TreeNode selectedNode) {  
        this.selectedNode = selectedNode;  
    }  

    public void displaySelectedSingle(ActionEvent event) {  
        if(selectedNode != null) {  
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Selected", selectedNode.getData().toString());  

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);  
        }  
    } 

    public String getTestt()
    {
        if(selectedNode!=null)
        return selectedNode.getData().toString()+" of 2011  ............Events....";

        else
            return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem. Here is a right code of bean:

```
 public class TreeBean{

private TreeNode root;
  private TreeNode selectedNode;  


 public TreeBean() {  

        root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);  
        TreeNode node0 = new DefaultTreeNode("2011", root);  
        TreeNode node1 = new DefaultTreeNode("2012", root);  
        TreeNode node2 = new DefaultTreeNode("2013", root);  


        EnumMonths[] arrayMonth=EnumMonths.values();

        TreeNode[] treelar=new TreeNode[arrayMonth.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayMonth.length; i++) {

            treelar[i]=new DefaultTreeNode(arrayMonth[i], node0);
        }

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayAylar.length; i++) {

                treelar[i]=new DefaultTreeNode(arrayMonth[i], node1);
            }

          for (int i = 0; i < arrayMonth.length; i++) {

            treelar[i]=new DefaultTreeNode(arrayMonth[i], node2);
            }

    }  

    public TreeNode getRoot() {  
        return root;  
    }  

    public TreeNode getSelectedNode() {  
        return selectedNode;  
    }  

    public void setSelectedNode(TreeNode selectedNode) {  
        this.selectedNode = selectedNode;  
    }  

    public void displaySelectedSingle(ActionEvent event) {  
        if(selectedNode != null) {  
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Selected", selectedNode.getData().toString());  

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);  
        }  
    } 

    public String getTestt()
    {
        if(selectedNode!=null)
        return selectedNode.getData().toString()+" of "+ selectedNode.getParent().getData().toString()+" ............Events....";


        else
            return "";
    }
```

}